# Why MS Dynamics CRM SDK dll are not obfuscated

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2013

While using dynamics CRM SDK Dlls, I found that they are not obfuscated and using ILSpy de-compiler we can easily view code written by Microsoft.

Why are they not obfuscated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should they be obfuscated? The SDK is free and the dll's that are part of it only are useful in the context of the Dynamics CRM eco system.